# couldn't compile regular expression pattern: quantifier operand invalid error when trying to substring in tcl with regexp

Tags: regex, string, tcl

I have a string like `ED-SNC::SNC0-1-2:101:::RTEOPR=REGROOM,TYPE=DYNAMIC` and I want to get the `TYPE=DYNAMIC` from it and save it in a variable.
I do `set editParam [regexp $line {(?<=,).*$}]` and I get error:

couldn't compile regular expression pattern: quantifier operand invalid
what am I missing here?

Comment: Note incorrect syntax: it should be `regexp {(?<=,).*$} $line` if only lookbehinds worked.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Tcl regex engine does not support lookbehinds (which are horribly costly), so it can't parse the expression.

If you know there is a comma, you can do the same thing more simply by

```
string range $line [string last , $line]+1 end
```

or

```
regexp {[^,]+$} $line var
```

or

```
regexp {\w+=\w+$} $line var
```

If there might not be a comma and you only want to get the string if there is a comma, use

```
if {[set idx [string last , $line]] >= 0} {
    set var [string range $line $idx+1 end]
}
```

or

```
regexp {,([^,]+)$} $line -> var
```

You get two results here: the full match goes into the `->` variable, and the captured text goes into the variable `var`. None of those change if there is no match.

Comment: `lindex [split $line ","] end` might be another alternative depending on OP's data.

Comment: @Peter Lewerin Thanks regexp {,([^,]+)$} $line -> editParam worked